# error building UDF mysql:relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: mysql, shared-libraries, rake, user-defined-functions, udf

I'm trying to build a UDF library using rake:

```
task :compile do
    system("gcc -L/usr/local/lib -lgmp -lpaillier `mysql_config --cflags` -c -fPIC #{FILE}.c")
    system("ar -x /usr/local/lib/libpaillier.a")
    system("gcc -shared *.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lgmp -o #{LIBFILE}")
    system("sudo mv #{LIBFILE} /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/")
end
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: paillier.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
paillier.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/lib -lgmp -lpaillier `mysql_config --cflags` -c -fPIC #{FILE}.c
```

you are compiling an object file whose name will be the value of `#{FILE}.o` -
let's say it is `aa.o` - and you are compiling it with Position-Independent Code
(`-fPIC`). Your linker flags:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lgmp -lpaillier
```

serve no purpose here and are ignored because no linking is being done.

Here:

```
ar -x /usr/local/lib/libpaillier.a
```

you are extracting all of the object files from the static library `/usr/local/lib/libpaillier.a`. There is in fact just
one object file in the library, `paillier.o`

Here:

```
gcc -shared *.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lgmp -o #{LIBFILE}
```

you are building a shared library whose name will be the value of `#{LIBFILE}`
- let's say it is `libfoo.so` - linking the object files `aa.o`, `paillier.o`,
plus `libgmp`.

Extracting the object file `paillier.o` from `libpaillier.a` to link it with `libfoo.so`
achieves nothing different from *not* extracting it and simply linking
`libpaillier.a` itself, i.e nothing different from:

```
gcc -shared #{FILE}.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpaillier -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lgmp -o #{LIBFILE}
```

And the linkage library paths:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

are superflous because both of those paths are default linker search paths on your system.

But *a shared library must be built entirely from PIC object code*. `aa.o` was compiled
with `-fPIC`, in your first step. However, `paillier.o` was not not. So the linkage fails and the linker
advises you that `paillier.o` must be recompiled with `-fPIC`.

So do that:-

Delete your existing `/usr/local/lib/libpaillier.a` and `/usr/local/include/paillier.h`

Go back to your `libpaillier` source directory (where you built it first time).

Clean it up:

```
$ make clean
```

Reconfigure the autotools build system to compile PIC code:

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC [and whatever other options you used before]
```

Rebuild:

```
$ make
```

Reinstall:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Now you again have a header `/usr/local/include/paillier.h` and
a static library `/usr/local/lib/libpaillier.a` but this time
the `paillier.o` in the library is PIC code.

Then you can build your plugin with:

```
task :compile do
    system("gcc `mysql_config --cflags` -c -fPIC #{FILE}.c")
    system("gcc -shared #{FILE}.o -lpaillier -lgmp -o #{LIBFILE}")
    system("sudo mv #{LIBFILE} /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/")
end
```

Comment: you were right that worked perfectly , thank you so much

Comment: @Bochra You're welcome - and welcome to Stackoverflow!